# Calling PHP methods with varying arguments

Tags: php, api, oop

I'm writing an API class, and my general goal is for it to be easy to make any class's methods accessible via the API, without having to make any serious changes to the class itself. Essentially, I should be able to instantiate an API class instance on any class that I want to use (within my little framework), and have it just work.

For example, In my API class, I have a method `call`, that I want to use `$_GET` to call the correct function from the class that I want to make accessible (let's call it `Beep`). So I specify an `action` parameter in my API, so that the `action` is the method of `Beep` to call, with the remaining arguments in `$_GET` being, presumably, the arguments for the method. In `API->call`, I can do `$BeepInstance->$_GET['action']()`, but I have no way of determining which arguments from $_GET to send, and in what order to send them.

`func_get_args` will only return the list of given arguments for the function in which it is called, and I don't necessarily know the correct order in which to pass them with `call_user_func_array`.

Has anyone tried to do something similar to this?

Comment: You can use PHP's reflection facilities to find the name and order of a method's arguments.  But it's kind of kludgey.

Comment: @FrankFarmer Can you add some explanation to that or a link to a good resource on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution + example that uses reflection to map your input arguments to method parameters. I also added a way to control which methods are exposed to make it more secure.

```
class Dispatch {
    private $apis;

    public function registerAPI($api, $name, $exposedActions) {
        $this->apis[$name] = array(
            'api' => $api,
            'exposedActions' => $exposedActions
        );
    }

    public function handleRequest($apiName, $action, $arguments) {
        if (isset($this->apis[$apiName])) {
            $api = $this->apis[$apiName]['api'];
            // check that the action is exposed
            if (in_array($action, $this->apis[$apiName]['exposedActions'])) {
                // execute action

                // get method reflection & parameters
                $reflection = new ReflectionClass($api);
                $method = $reflection->getMethod($action);

                // map $arguments to $orderedArguments for the function
                $orderedArguments = array();

                foreach ($method->getParameters() as $parameter) {
                    if (array_key_exists($parameter->name, $arguments)) {
                        $orderedArguments[] = $arguments[$parameter->name];
                    } else if ($parameter->isOptional()) {
                        $orderedArguments[] = $parameter->getDefaultValue();
                    } else {
                        throw new InvalidArgumentException("Parameter {$parameter->name} is required");
                    }
                }

                // call method with ordered arguments
                return call_user_func_array(array($api, $action), $orderedArguments);
            } else {
                throw new InvalidArgumentException("Action {$action} is not exposed");
            }
        } else {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("API {$apiName} is not registered");
        }
    }
}

class Beep {
    public function doBeep($tone = 15000)
    {
        echo 'beep at ' . $tone;
    }

    public function notExposedInAPI()
    {
        // do secret stuff
    }
}
```

Example:

```
// dispatch.php?api=beep&action=doBeep&tone=20000

$beep = new Beep();
$dispatch = new Dispatch();
$dispatch->registerAPI($beep, 'beep', array('doBeep'));

$dispatch->handleRequest($_GET['api'], $_GET['action'], $_GET);
```

Comment: This is absolutely awesome. Looks like exactly what I was looking for. I'll mess around with it for a bit.

Answer (score 1):

We did something similar in our API. We used a proxy method _methodName($p) and passed in the $_GET or $_REQUEST array. The proxy method knows the order of the parameters required for the real method, so it invokes the real method correctly. Using call_user_func_array() worked pretty well with that.

Not sure if that's the best way to go about it, but it works well for us.

The controller looks something like this:

```
if (method_exists($server, "_$method"))
        $resp = call_user_func_array("{$server}::_$method", array($_REQUEST));
```

And then the model is setup like:

```
public function test($arg1, $arg2) { ... }
public function _test($p) {
    return $this->test($p['arg1'], $p['arg2']);
}
```

Comment: I thought about this, but I wish there was a more abstracted way to do it, rather than writing these little proxies for every method I want to be accessible. But I suppose this also makes security a little better, since it means explicitly defining the accessible methods.

Also, why not then just call the method in the normal way, inside the proxy? call_user_func_array() seems to have a pretty huge speed penalty.

Comment: @pettazz, the class we're calling it on varies, and the version of php we're using doesn't support `$server::method()` Because we're also using xmlrpc2 to support xmlrpc requests, the server methods need to be static. Otherwise we would.

Comment: Agreed that writing the proxy methods is a pain. I look forward to seeing what others come up with. Good question.

Answer (score 1):

I'd propose to **pass an associative array** the the respective method. Since the assoc. array provides a name to value mapping.

Moreover, **never** do something like this:

```
  $BeepInstance->$_GET['action']()
```

This is highly insecure.

Probably define another associate array, which maps actions passed as GET 'action' parameters to actual method names.

Comment: `$BeepInstance->$_GET['action']()`  I know, it was just an example, since I didn't want to bog down my explanation with details not directly related to the question.

Comment: Also, passing an associative array would work, but that requires the methods to accept parameters in that way, and also adds a significant amount of checking for required args that php would normally handle on its own.

Comment: Hm, I don't see the point. The method has to check for appropriate arguments anyway. Thus, I don't believe, that there is significant overhead. Anyways, the desicion is more or less one of philosophy.

Comment: The overhead comes in terms of whether PHP itself will check for required arguments and add defaults, or whether I have to do that myself in my methods. It's the difference between a one line method and a 5 line method with a bunch of array operations at the beginning. I'm not saying it's necessarily _slower_, just that why reinvent a wheel that works perfectly already?